# Enable Demographics and Interest Reports with Modernizer JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

So, after reading the Google help docs on how to proceed, we have to change our code from this:

`ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';`

To this:

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
```

Our code currently says this (preceded by a modernizer javascript load):

```
 <script>
        window._gaq = [['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-XX'],['_trackPageview'],['_trackPageLoadTime']];
        Modernizr.load({
            load: ('https:' == location.protocol ? '//ssl' : '//www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'
        });
    </script>
```

I'm not sure how to modify our code. I'm assuming we'd just have to change it to this:

```
load: ('https:' == location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://’) + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js'
```

OR would it be like this?

```
load: ('https:' == location.protocol ?-Empty Quotes here or Nothing-) + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js'
```